# How to return different data types in parse function using backbone

Tags: rest, parsing, backbone.js

I have a web service that returns a list of documents and the size of the list.
My method in the web service looks like this :

```
public PaginatedJaxbList<DocumentDTO> listDocuments(String currentPage, String name) {
    List<DocumentDTO> docs= getDocsManager.getDocs(currentPage, name);
    int size = getDocsManager.getDocsSize();
    PaginatedJaxbList<DocumentDTO> docList = new PaginatedJaxbList<DocumentDTO>(docs, size);
    return docList;
}
```

This method is called by the rest web service like this :

```
@WebService
@Path("/docs")
public interface docService {

@GET
@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8")
public PaginatedJaxbList<DocumentDTO> listDocs(@QueryParam("p") String currentPage, @QueryParam("name") String name);
}
```

Now i parse the response of the web service fron the parse function in backbone Collection:

```
    Entities.DocumentCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url : "../services/api/docs",
        model : Entities.Document,
        comparator : "name",
        parse : function(data) {
            // Here i need to return both params the size and the list
            //return data.size;
            //return data.list;
        }
    });
```

In the parse function i need to get both of the parameters  the list to be displayed and it's size for the dynamic pagination need.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Collections parse method should return an array of objects, a model will be created corresponding to each item in the array, or an object, in which case single model will be created.

So you should only return the array, but you can attach the other properties to the collection to be accessed later as follows:

```
Entities.DocumentCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url : "../services/api/docs",
    model : Entities.Document,
    comparator : "name",
    parse : function(data) {
        this.size = data.size; // add size as a collection property
        return data.list; // return the list from which models should be populated
    }
});
```